# "Nested" array within db response using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, codeigniter

I am trying to create a "nested" array within an object that I am returning from a database.

I can have more than one footnote per "thing".

This is what I am currently getting back:

**JSON**

```
{
"data": [{
        "id": "123",
        "type": "foo",
        "color": "bar",
        "footnote_id": "1",
        "footnote_text": " Footnote one"
    }]
}
```

Here is the result I'm trying to generate:

**JSON**

```
{
"data": [{
        "id": "123",
        "type": "foo",
        "color": "bar",
        "footnotes": [{
                "footnote_id": "1",
                "footnote_text": " Footnote one"
            },
            {
                "footnote_id": "2",
                "footnote_text": "Footnote two"
            }]
    }]
}
```

I have a `footnotes` table that has all kinds of footnotes (`footnote_id` and such).
I have a `type` table that has all kinds of things in it (`type_id` and such).
I also have a `type_footnotes` table that only has two columns: `type_id` and `footnote_id`

I'm not sure how to create the `footnotes` property of the response object - then display the results within that array.

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT**

Here is the query - I thought I had posted this as well. My apologies.

**PHP**

```
 public function get_thing($type_id) {
    $this->db->select('type.type_id, type.type, type.type_color');

    $this->db->join('footnotes', 'footnotes.footnote_id, footnotes.footnote_text');
    $this->db->join('type_footnotes, type_footnotes.type_id = type.type_id');

    $query = $this->db->get_where('type', array('type.type_id' => $type_id), 1);

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the limit, and post here what do you get as result :

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('type', array('type.type_id' => $type_id));
```